# Barcode decoding in android-phonegap app

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I'm developing an android-phonegap application where I have to decode the barcode of my student ID and barcode of a library book .First I have to capture the barcodes through the mobile camera connected to the application.
Here is the .js code i have written

scancode.js

```
    window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(function(result) {

    alert("We got a barcode\n" +
             "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
             "Format: " + result.format + "\n" + 
              "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);

    }, function(error) {  

    alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
    }
    );
```

here is the html file which I get the barcode details

burrow.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

    <head>
    <title>Burrow</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="PopUpBox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Connect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="BarCode.js"></script>

    </head>
    <form>
    <body>
    <FORM>
     <INPUT Type="button" style="background-color:#4682B4" VALUE="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;">

    </FORM>
    <br><br>
    <img src="../www/images/pic.jpg" style="width:300px;height:80px;">
    <br><br><br>


<center><input type="button" style="background-color:#2F4F4F;width:230px;height:45px;text-align:center;color:#DCDCDC;font-size:1.5em" onClick="window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan( function(result)" value="Scan Student ID"></center>
 <br>
 <center><input type="button" style="background-color:#2F4F4F;width:230px;height:45px;text-align:center;color:#DCDCDC;font-size:1.5em" onClick="window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan( function(result)" value="Scan Book ID"></center>

 <br><br>
<center><input type="button" style="background-color:#2F4F4F;width:230px;height:45px;text-align:center;color:#DCDCDC;font-size:1.5em" onClick="Burrow_Confirmation()" value="Burrow"></center><br/>
    </body>
    </form>
    </html>
```

I have created to barcode scanner library according to documentation.My coding does not work.Can you please give a solution??

Comment: did u add plugin to config.xml  ?

Comment: yes :( do u think it's not a fault in the coding???

Comment: Are you including your `scancode.js` file somewhere? What do you mean "my coding does not work?" Can you provide some error messages and a description of what happens?

Answer (score 0):

For Barcode Scanner i have used this plugin https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner. It must be the same one that you have used. If so, make sure you added the zxing project to your eclipse and reference it in the project and add the necessary zxing activity settings to your application manifest file. Check the information provided in this link https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner

Comment: yeah i used that.And i'v done all that is mentioned in the link you gave as well .Can you give me a sample code on how to use this library in my coding to get the barcode and decode if can?

Comment: Are you getting any specific error. What is it that is not working?

Comment: I don't get any errors .But i get some warning .Also I can't run the app in the emulator.It happened only after connecting with the barcode scanner library

Comment: Barcodescanner will not be working in the emulator as it needs hardware camera. Try testing it on a device

Comment: barcode scanning part working fine now .I further need to get push notifications to my app .and i'm using google api,I have done all the things in the following link http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/ but when running i do not get the Alert box which is said in that tutorial.it gives the following error in console     Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED